# Hmaster unexpectedly stopping while starting Hbase

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hadoop2

While starting hbase , hmaster is exiting abruptly with the follwing error :-

```
    2015-07-17 20:52:36,136 DEBUG [main] master.HMaster: master/master/218.93.250.18:60000 HConnection server-to-server retries=350
    2015-07-17 20:52:37,969 ERROR [main] master.HMasterCommandLine: Master exiting
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed construction of Master: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.constructMaster(HMaster.java:3015)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:3029)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.bind(RpcServer.java:2462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer$Listener.<init>(RpcServer.java:588)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.<init>(RpcServer.java:1942)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.<init>(HMaster.java:512)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.constructMaster(HMaster.java:3010)
```

Please suggest a reason. 
Following is my hbase-site.xml file :-

```
    <configuration>
    <property>
 <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
 <value>hdfs://localhost:54310/hbase</value>
 </property>

 <property>
 <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
 <value>true</value>
 </property>

 <property>
 <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
 <value>localhost</value>
 </property>

 <property>
 <name>dfs.replication</name>
 <value>1</value>
 </property>

 <property>
 <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
 <value>2181</value>
 </property>

 <property>
 <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
 <value>/home/hduser/zookeeperData</value>
 </property>

 </configuration>
```

following is my hosts file configuration.

```
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    127.0.0.1       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
    ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
    fe00::0 ip6-localnet
    ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
    ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
    ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Whats going wrong in this???